# How does Tor Metrics estimate client location?

Tags: exit-relays, guard-node

Tor Metrics provides data on client location at the country level. How is this data estimated? I assume it does so with the CollecTor data? How does one back the country out from that information? I looked for an academic paper but couldn't find one. I'm just trying to make sense of the CollecTor data and want to make sure I understand what is and isn't there.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you maybe aware, one must have correct time for Tor to work. This will provide a crucial piece of information to estimate the geo-location of clients to Tor. There are two sets of information that can be deducted from this information.

1. The approximate location of clients on the globe.
2. The time interval that daylight saving time applies (or do not applies) to a particular geo-location may also be used to pin point the geo-location of the clients. For example in India the day light saving time does not apply at all. Meaning the time does not change based on the season, while in US, most of the year is in daylight timing zone.